# How to search for emails "on hold opt out" and not "on hold bounce"

Tags: civimail

We experienced a severe network problem across many ISP's this week that resulted in a bunch of email non deliveries. I now have many email addresses marked as on hold, I think because of the unusual network problems. I want to unhold these addresses, but do not want to unhold emails where addressees opted out.

Is there a way to search for emails that are on hold because of bounces, and not because they opted out. (alternatively can I search for emails that are on hold because of an opt out, and not because of bounce processing).

Thanks
Davy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perfectly get the result you want navigating to **Search - Advanced Search** and expand the **Mailings** section, from there you can search for bounced emails or opt-out request specifying a date range.

If you cannot see the Mailings section navigate to **Administer - Customize Data and Screens - Display Preferences** and make sure you have Mailing ticked under **Contact Search**

You can do the same from **Search - Search Builder** selecting Contact as record type and On Hold or No Bulk emails(User Opt Out) as the field.

You can also bulk **Unhold Emails** from the action menu in the search result, selecting the contacts you think they shouldn't be on hold.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Andrei - thanks for the comprehensive answer.  That was exactly what I was looking for. My Mailing section wasn't visible and as soon as I fixed that I found what I needed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do some sort of 'when on earth did all our records get put 'on hold' you can do a sequel search on the 'hold_date field eg

```
SELECT
  Year(hold_date),
  Month(hold_date),
  Count(*) As Total_Rows,
  Count(id) As Rows_With_Attribute
FROM civicrm_email
GROUP BY Year(hold_date), Month(hold_date)
```